# Hiding the PayPal Credit button on Braintree JavaScript v4 SDK

Tags: javascript, paypal, braintree, braintree-sandbox, braintree-javascript

*I'm posting this here in the hope there are some Braintree/PayPal engineers looking at StackOverflow for support issues. I have submitted a support ticket through their new form twice, but have had no reply.*

We have noticed very recently that the "PayPal Credit" button has appeared on our payment page **without any code changes** by us to turn this on.

How we would disable this?

[image: PayPal Credit]

Also, is it default behaviour to display this on sandbox accounts only? This does not seem to be affecting our production environment (yet).

We are using v4 of the JavaScript SDK:

```
braintreeClient: "https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.87.0/js/client.min",
hosted_fields: "https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.87.0/js/hosted-fields.min",
checkoutJs: "https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min",
paypalCheckout: "https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.87.0/js/paypal-checkout.min"
```

I have tried passing through `offerCredit: false`, but this has had no effect:

```
// Set up PayPal with the checkout.js library
paypal.Button.render({
    env: '{{ braintree_env }}', // 'sandbox' or 'production'
    style: {
        label: 'paypal',
        size:  'responsive',    // small | medium | large | responsive
        shape: 'rect',     // pill | rect
        color: 'white',     // gold | blue | silver | black
        tagline: false,
        width: 500,
        height: 55
    },
    payment: function () {
        return paypalCheckoutInstance.createPayment({
            flow: 'vault', // required to allow us to charge the account in future without re-authentication
            offerCredit: false
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

For the (v4) checkout.js, which is deprecated, enabling or disabling the credit button on an existing account likely requires an account-level toggle, so Braintree/PayPal will need to do it for you.

Edit: try adding this within the `paypal.Button.render(`:

```js
    funding: {
        disallowed: [window.paypal.FUNDING.CREDIT]
    },
```

Current (v5) JS SDK integrations have fundingSource parameter to render specific buttons. (as well as a disable-funding script parameter if rendering multiple smart ones, but it's not as useful with Braintree)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have reached out to Braintree 3 times now without reply. Since they moved from email support to a form the support seems to have dropped off a cliff.

Comment: added suggestion